# Why a result of a division is automatically int in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this line:

```
Console.WriteLine((double)(1 / 4)));
```

which outputs: `0`.

I debugged it, and the compiler is treating `1 / 4` as 0:

[image: compiler converts 1 / 4 to 0]

So as I understand it, the compiler treats `1 / 4` as `int`. But why?

---

**Note:** when I write this line:

```
Console.WriteLine((double)1 / 4));
```

it outputs: `0.25`.

Comment: when you divite two integers the result is a integer

Comment: Whole numbers without any qualifiers are literal integers. Numbers with decimals in them without any qualifiers are literal doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `1` and `4` both are `int`s. There is no reason for the compiler to make type-conversions. Run this sample and see the outputs:

```
int x = 1, y = 4;

Console.WriteLine(x / y);

double xx = 1;
Console.WriteLine(xx / y);

double yy = 4;
Console.WriteLine(x / yy);
```

Comment: So that's why the second line is working? Because I cast `1` to `double`, and `double` divided by `int`, is a double?

Answer (score 1):

if you divide `int` by an `int` you get an `int` as result.

if you want to have a `double` as result you need at least one parameter that is a `double`.
A short way to designate a double is to set a `.0` after the number

```
Console.WriteLine(1 / 4.0);
Console.WriteLine(1.0 / 4);
```

this would be interpreted as `double`